# Change colour of ionicon content

Tags: html, css

I need to check colour of the X in ionicon but can't change the x itself. I can either change the background-color or actual color of the circle.

Is there a way to change ONLY the x?

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.ion-ios-close-circle.a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.ion-ios-close-circle.b {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <i class="a ion-ios-close-circle"></i>
      <i class="b ion-ios-close-circle"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So eventually I need to achieve this

[image]

Comment: Is it a requirement that the `x` remain white?

Comment: It is a desired result. Purely personal preference and I'd like to achieve this. If the x stays transparent, other images behind it cover up the x. For example you can't see the X on a black image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a border radius with the background-colour and absolute poitioning to centre the icon:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.ion-ios-close-circle {
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.ion-ios-close-circle:before {
  display:inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.a {
  background-color: white;
}

.b {
  background-color: orange;
}

/* ie11 only move icon down 1px */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .ion-ios-close-circle:before {
      margin-top:1px;
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <i class="a ion-ios-close-circle"></i>
    <i class="b ion-ios-close-circle"></i>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk should work in ie now - has dirty little hack at the end to move it down a pixel so it look more like the other browsers but I think it may be caused by the font being used for ie is different to the ones for the other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the SVG of ionicons isnt rounded, you can try with FontAwesome

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.fas.fa-times-circle.c {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
  font-size:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
 border: none;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
    
      <i class="c fas fa-times-circle"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, this ionicon is used across the app and I can't just switch icons. I have to stick to the current style.